# Database architecture for multiple types of user with multiple roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have one requirement. it's basically school management. One school model is there. 
Possible number of users with roles

1. Student
2. Teacher
3. Parents
4. Principal
5. School Admin
6. Super Admin

Teacher can have different fields like experience, education, taken subjects like that, Student can have different fields like stream, standard, divison etc. I don't want to use STI concept because there would be fields which are differ for student, teacher, parents.

What i am thinking is it would also have relationships like 
student has many teacher
teacher has many students, 
Student has many parents
Parents has many students.

How could i build architecture for this requirement?

Comment: You can use STI concept. But if your only problem is with having different fields, then you can store meta information in a new table, that's what WordPress do. You can look for the concept called the Entity-Attribute-Value-Model approach.

Answer (score 0):

So you can use user as base model for each role, and use different type of roles as different tables with one User to many Student(s)(as example)

Here is fast example with base tables for resolving this question. You can add Parents tables same steps as Teachers to Students

[Simple ER diagram here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toCzE.png)